# Django - Pass Object ID after redirect

Tags: python, django

Apologies if the question title is wrong but I am unsure of exactly what I need to do. I am building a scrum app where users can create user stories and add them to sprints. I want to have two separate ways of creating stories. If the user is creating a story from the backlog, the story that has been created will not be assigned to a sprint, but the user can also add a story from a sprint's detail screen. I want to make it so that if they add a story from a specific sprint's page, that story's sprint field is populated with that sprint.

The way I have tried to go about this is by creating two different functions in my views.py file and two separate templates. I am able to create the story without relating to a sprint as intended, but I cannot think of a way to get the id of the sprint where I navigated from to get to the new template.

For reference I have included my function for creating stories without relating to a sprint:

```
def create_story(response, id=None):
    user = response.user
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewUserStory(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            status = form.cleaned_data["status"]
            assignee = form.cleaned_data["assignee"]
            estimate = form.cleaned_data["estimate"]
            userstory = UserStory(name=name, description=description, status=status, assignee=assignee, estimate=estimate)
            userstory.save()
            response.user.userstories.add(userstory)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/backlog")
    else:
        form = CreateNewUserStory()
    return render(response, "main/create_story.html", {"form": form})
```

If any more information or code is required please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2 URLs, one with an optional sprint ID:

`urls.py`:

```
path('story/<int:sprint_id>/add/', views.create_story, name='create_story_for_sprint'),
path('story/add/', views.create_story, name='create_story_for_backlog'),
```

`views.py`:

```
def create_story(request, sprint_id=None):
   ...
   form = CreateNewUserStory(response.POST, initial={"sprint_id": sprint_id})
   if form.is_valid():
       ...
       sprint_id = form.cleaned_data["sprint_id"]
```

`create_story.html`:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="sprint_id" value="{{ sprint_id|default_if_none:'' }}">
    ...
```

Then, in your sprint page, use

```
<a href="{% url 'create_story_for_sprint' sprint.id %}">Add Story</a>
```

and in your backlog page:

```
<a href="{% url 'create_story_for_backlog' %}">Add Story</a>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your response. I am trying to implement but I am running into some Key Errors, am I just not converting the naming correctly or would it make a difference that a Sprint is a Model which is a foreignkey for Story?

Comment: You must have a `sprint_id` field in your `CreateNewUserStory`. I also suggest you to use a `ModelForm` instead of a `Form` so that you won't have to manually process each field yourself.

Comment: So I have updated the form to a ModelForm as follows:
```class CreateNewUserStory(forms.ModelForm):

    
    class Meta:

        model = UserStory

        fields = ('name', 'description', 'status', 'assignee', 'estimate')

        widgets = {'description':Textarea(),}
```

Do I add sprint_id next to 'name', 'description' etc.? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Note that my answer was to suggest a method to implement what you asked in your question. If you are having unrelated issues they might be difficult to resolve in comments. You can always post a new question, with your updated code, and any error messages you are getting (with full traceback).

Comment: I believe I may having issues because I don't have an 'id' field for sprint, and am just utilising the automatic id for the objects. Thank you for taking the time to answer and comment though, hopefully I am able to figure it out from the concept you gave above.

Comment: Can you post your models please? The `id` column in your `Sprint` model is irrelevant as this form is about the `Story` model. I assumed that your `Story` model has a nullable foreign key to your `Sprint` model. In that case Django will automatically create a `sprint_id` column in your `<app>_story` table.

Comment: Apologies about the delay in responding. I couldn't make a further edit so I have asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177367/django-pass-object-after-redirect and included my models.py file in the question.